# Blur content on modal show event

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to change a class where all my site content resides (wrapper), basically when user clicks in a modal to open, I add styling to a class "**wrapper**", I'm using the `.modal-backgrop.in` CSS to add one more CSS that is the blur, but doesn't work.

Here is style:

```
.modal-backdrop.in+#wrapper {
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    -moz-filter: blur(10px);
    -o-filter: blur(10px);
    -ms-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Comment: Please post full relevant code by creating a snippet or a fiddle

Comment: what are you trying to style? The wrapper or the modal-backdrop? What is the HTML that corresponds to this?

Comment: Your wrapper element isn't a class, it's selected as an id ("#name" means "html element with id=name"). Did you mean ".wrapper"?

Comment: @epascarello im trying to style the wrapper when the modal-backdrop is fired

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to make what is behind the modal blurry. To obtain this effects, you can try one of these approaches:

### Using [`backdrop-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter)

This one is still an [experimental CSS property](https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=css-backdrop-filter); it is, however, quite straightforward, as it applies a filter to what is behind a semi-transparent element. An implementation of this method would be:

```css
.modal-backdrop.in + #wrapper {
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);  
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Note that, as it is still experimental, it shouldn't be used in production.

### Styling the page itself

With JavaScript, you can add a class to the `#wrapper` element, such as `.modal-open`, and then style it appropriately, more or less like this (remember remove the filter from the modal if it is inside the wrapper):

**JS**

```
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

function openModal () {
    // ...
    wrapper.classList.add('modal-open');
}

function closeModal () {
    // ...
    wrapper.classList.remove('modal-open');
}
```

**CSS**

```css
#wrapper.modal-open {
    filter: blur(10px);
}

#modal {
    filter: none;
}
```